# Parallelize function calls in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

using python3.6.9 i want to achieve the following:

having a list with client-ips i want to ping each client for monitoring purposes. using a for-loop leads to the problem, that it takes quite long time until it finishes, especially if some pings have to wait for a timeout.
so i thought of running each ping in a separate task.

how would i do it?
currently it looks like this:

```
for i in vpnClients:
    response_list=pythonping.ping(vpnClients[i]['virtualAddress'], count=2)
    singleStat={ "measurement": "ping", "tags": { "virtual ip": vpnClients[i]['virtualAddress']}, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow(), "fields": { "min": float(response_list.rtt_min_ms), "max": float(response_list.rtt_max_ms), "avg": float(response_list.rtt_avg_ms) }}
    json_body.append(singleStat)
```

if instead of performing the pythonping i would want to do a async call to a function (i could wrap that like:

```
 def doPing(ip):
    response_list=pythonping.ping(vpnClients[ip]['virtualAddress'], count=2)
    singleStat={ "measurement": "ping", "tags": { "virtual ip": vpnClients[ip]['virtualAddress']}, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow(), "fields": { "min": float(response_list.rtt_min_ms), "max": float(response_list.rtt_max_ms), "avg": float(response_list.rtt_avg_ms) }}
    json_body.append(singleStat)


 for i in vpnClients:
    call_function(doPing(i))
```

is that possible?

thx,
andre

Comment: The possible options are multi-threading or concurrency. The most common python libraries for this task are `concurrent.futures` (multi-threading/multiprocessing) or `asyncio` (concurrency). Just do a Google search and you will find plenty of tutorials/answers etc

Comment: I think it's not that trivial @NomadMonad. Pythonping implementation is blocking therefore asyncio is out unless you run in executor (eg. using concurrent.futures) however pythonping socket implementation is not thread safe, you can not use it for concurrent pings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that simple that it seems. Ideally, the pythonping package does provide some multitarget API but it doesn't (in 2020 apr). Unfortunately the pythonping package is not thread safe either, therefore you can not go the threadpool way (and you can not use asyncio as suggested, because pythonping is not async capable). If you check out [the source](https://github.com/alessandromaggio/pythonping/blob/master/pythonping/executor.py), you can see, it's simply checking for ICMP packets and can not differentiate by target.

```
while time_left > 0:
        # Keep listening until a packet arrives
        raw_packet, source_socket, time_left = self.socket.receive(time_left)
        # If we actually received something
        if raw_packet != b'':
            response.unpack(raw_packet)
            # Ensure we have not unpacked the packet we sent (RHEL will also listen to outgoing packets)
            if response.id == packet_id and response.message_type !=  icmp.Types.EchoRequest.type_id:
return Response(Message('', response, source_socket[0]), timeout-time_left)
```

If we send out 10 packets the first reply would confirm all targets. Not cool.

What is left, is the process-pool way. If we really want to use the async api something like this:

```
import datetime
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import pythonping

# python 3.6 we had had to do this:
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

vpnClients = [
        {'virtualAddress': '192.168.111.113'},
        {'virtualAddress': '192.168.111.1'},
        {'virtualAddress': '192.168.111.100'},
        ]


def myping(client):
    target = client['virtualAddress']
    res = pythonping.ping(target, count=2, timeout=2)
    return { "measurement": "ping", "tags": { "virtual ip": target}, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow(), "fields": { "min": float(res.rtt_min_ms), "max": float(res.rtt_max_ms), "avg": float(res.rtt_avg_ms) }}


async def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
        executors = [loop.run_in_executor(pool, myping, c) for c in vpnClients]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*executors)

    print(result)


# You could do this if you would have python 3.7
# asyncio.run(main())
# but for 3.6, we must:
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

We must use the custom `myping` function because process pool executor functions **must** return picklable objects hence pythonping's ResponseList wouldn't work. The dict you are using is just fine (it's picklable).

Of course you could simply use the multiprocessing API.

However if your network is stable and fast (virtualhosts?) it might be better to lower the timeout to something small.

```
 pythonping.ping(target, count=2, timeout=0.1)
```

Comment: thanks - i think i will go the timeout way - it is simpler than the rest, but a good approach. thx a lot.
btw: if i call the script on linux in parallel, would that work (with different target lists of course)? since different processes would cause the ping it should work, right?

regards,
andre

Comment: Yes, of course if you call it parallel at the operating system level it will work, just like you can run many standard ping commands parallel,  but I thought this is what you want to avoid.